# Hardware error from APEI Generic Hardware Error Source: 5

Tags: logs, hardware

This appears in my Dell XR12. I am using an [Intel ACC100 (PDF download)](https://cdrdv2.intel.com/v1/dl/getContent/642103) acceleration card . But I dont understand the error. What is happening here? Any help is appreciated!

```
[Thu Sep  7 08:43:27 2023] loop10: detected capacity change from 0 to 8
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:23 2023] {1}[Hardware Error]: Hardware error from APEI Generic Hardware Error Source: 5
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:23 2023] {1}[Hardware Error]: event severity: recoverable
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:23 2023] {1}[Hardware Error]:  Error 0, type: fatal
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:23 2023] {1}[Hardware Error]:   section_type: PCIe error
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:23 2023] {1}[Hardware Error]:   port_type: 4, root port
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:23 2023] {1}[Hardware Error]:   version: 3.0
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:23 2023] {1}[Hardware Error]:   command: 0x0547, status: 0x4010
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:23 2023] {1}[Hardware Error]:   device_id: 0000:50:02.0
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:23 2023] {1}[Hardware Error]:   slot: 2
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:23 2023] {1}[Hardware Error]:   secondary_bus: 0x51
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:23 2023] {1}[Hardware Error]:   vendor_id: 0x8086, device_id: 0x347a
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:23 2023] {1}[Hardware Error]:   class_code: 060400
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:23 2023] {1}[Hardware Error]:   bridge: secondary_status: 0x2000, control: 0x0003
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:23 2023] {1}[Hardware Error]:   aer_uncor_status: 0x00000020, aer_uncor_mask: 0x01310000
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:23 2023] {1}[Hardware Error]:   aer_uncor_severity: 0x044ef030
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:23 2023] {1}[Hardware Error]:   TLP Header: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:23 2023] pcieport 0000:50:02.0: AER: aer_status: 0x00000020, aer_mask: 0x01310000
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:23 2023] pcieport 0000:50:02.0:    [ 5] SDES                   (First)
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:23 2023] pcieport 0000:50:02.0: AER: aer_layer=Transaction Layer, aer_agent=Receiver ID
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:23 2023] pcieport 0000:50:02.0: AER: aer_uncor_severity: 0x044ef030
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:24 2023] pcieport 0000:50:02.0: AER: Root Port link has been reset (0)
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:24 2023] pcieport 0000:50:02.0: AER: device recovery successful
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:24 2023] vfio-pci 0000:51:00.0: vfio_ecap_init: hiding ecap 0x19@0x248
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:37 2023] pci 0000:52:00.0: [8086:0d5d] type 00 class 0x120001
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:37 2023] pci 0000:52:00.0: Adding to iommu group 96
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:37 2023] vfio-pci 0000:51:00.0: Captured SR-IOV VF 0000:52:00.0 driver_override
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:37 2023] pci 0000:52:00.1: [8086:0d5d] type 00 class 0x120001
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:37 2023] pci 0000:52:00.1: Adding to iommu group 97
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:37 2023] vfio-pci 0000:51:00.0: Captured SR-IOV VF 0000:52:00.1 driver_override
[Thu Sep  7 08:44:50 2023] vfio-pci 0000:52:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding "Hardware error from APEI Generic Hardware Error Source" error message](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186724/understanding-hardware-error-from-apei-generic-hardware-error-source-error-mes)

Comment: and this one: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150451/apei-generic-hardware-error

Comment: Please run latest Memtest86 version from a USB to see if it is RAM issue.

Comment: I have ran memtest and there are no issues with the memory! I assume its related to the PCIe slot and the ACC100 accelerator. But I am not sure how to debug this and get more information. Thanks for you help so far!

Comment: Since this is a server we can safely assume it contains ECC RAM, but to test this out you would need likely a Professional version which is able to test ECC RAM. Normal version - the free one - is not capable of this. Cheers and good luck.

Comment: Yes you are right, I didnt rum memtest86+, I ran the ePSA tool from Dell which can be used for ECC RAM testing.