# Hardware error from APEI Generic Hardware Error Source (ECC RAM)

Tags: debian, memory, hardware, dmesg, ecc

```
[58306.633900] {1}[Hardware Error]: Hardware error from APEI Generic Hardware Error Source: 1
[58306.633905] {1}[Hardware Error]: It has been corrected by h/w and requires no further action
[58306.633907] {1}[Hardware Error]: event severity: corrected
[58306.633909] {1}[Hardware Error]:  Error 0, type: corrected
[58306.633911] {1}[Hardware Error]:  fru_text: CorrectedErr
[58306.633912] {1}[Hardware Error]:   section_type: memory error
[58306.633914] {1}[Hardware Error]:   node: 0 device: 44696
[58306.633916] {1}[Hardware Error]:   error_type: 2, single-bit ECC
```

This has appeared on my Debian Xeon server with **ECC RAM**, does it mean the RAM modules are dying or something else like an error caused by SW for example? I saw [some other post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/150451/126755) claiming his OS rebooted, while mine didn't, which is why I am asking. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ECC memory errors are always hardware errors, not software errors. That doesn’t mean that they indicate *failing* hardware, they can be caused by random bit flips. ([Google’s 2009 paper on the topic provides interesting insights](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1555349.1555372); its citations might provide more recent analyses.)

Hardware bit flips *can* be triggered by software, *e.g.* [in Rowhammer attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_hammer).

Unless the ECC errors become frequent, or you start seeing uncorrectable ECC errors, I wouldn’t worry about it.